# How to deleted a pattern matching of line using sed

Tags: unix

Hello everyone I am trying to delete lines using sed command:

What I have right now is :

```
$comp_args = "$comp_args -cover bsceft"
```

Output: I want to get rid off this line .

I tried this :

```
cat      <path to file > |\ sed '/comp_args -cover bsceft/d' |\ > <path_to_file>
```

Seems to be not working.

Comment: cat {path_to_file}  |\ sed '/comp_args -cover bsceft/d' > {path_to_file}

Comment: Good that you have shown your efforts in your question, could you please post samples of input and expected output in your question too for better understanding of question.

Comment: Input : 
$comp_args = ""
$comp_args = "$comp_args -64"
$comp_args = "$comp_args -cover bsceft" 
$comp_args = "$comp_args -mfcu"

Output :
$comp_args = ""
//$comp_args = "$comp_args -64" // Get rid of this line 
$comp_args = "$comp_args -cover bsceft"
$comp_args = "$comp_args -mfcu"

Answer (score 0):

I'd use `ed` instead of `sed` if you want to make changes the file in-place, as it, unlike `sed`, was designed from the start to edit files.

```sh
printf "%s\n" "/comp_args -cover bscheft/d" w | ed -s yourfile
```

will delete the first matching line and save the modified file.